# Manage multiple apps in 1 repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We are currently developing 5 travel iOS apps for 5 different countries. The code structure is the same for all those apps, except that multiple files has different content, such as API key's, Titles, Logo's and paths.

To avoid repeating ourself in doing changes/work, we like to have 1 repository with the main code, and beside that, kind of "sub-repositories" for the app depending files.

The question is, how can we get this result on Bitbucket?

Comment: You could use branches

Comment: or you could use [gitmodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)

Comment: *To avoid repeating ourself in doing changes/work, we like to have 1 repository with the main code, and beside that, kind of "sub-repositories" for the app depending files.* Can you not just like, use folders? `src/app`, `assets/app1`, `assets/app2` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach we use for such a situation is to organize the software into a library with the base functionality, and different directories for each specialized software component. The build system is so configured, that it build the library and all different software components together, so that a change in the library, which is needed for one component, but would break the others is detected early, when there is no pain to fix the components together.

We used different branches or subrepos for prior systems, but we always found ourselves in the merge hell short time later.